# Why I feel AWS SageMaker GPU not faster?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I spent 5 days configuring AWS SageMaker. ( contacting to increase GPU notebook limit costs 2 days, downloading and unzip all data cost 2 days, detours such as uploading data to S3 costs 1 day).

When I finally can run code on the SageMaker GPU notebook instance, I found the speed is not faster than my local CPU PC.
[image]

I used the following code to check GPU. Not sure what's going wrong. Does this happen to you pals? And my credits only have $200 left (Original $750).
[image]

Comment: Kaggle discussion suggests my code might spend too much time in video IO. I am gonna change preprocess. I am using the ml.p3.2xlarge instance which is actually fast.

Answer (score 2):

The problem should lie in video loading. When I train a Resnet model on an image dataset, the speed is pretty fast!! Thank you AWS !!
[image]

Regarding video loading strategy, I made this kernel for the comparison of different methods.

https://www.kaggle.com/muerbingsha/deepfake-face-detector-evaluate

It turns out `imageio_ffmpeg` is the fastest way.